# Is there a way to send an email about security updates?

Tags: security, admin

In Drupal there is an option to have an email sent periodically when there are updates (in general, or only security updates) available:

[image: Drupal security notification]

I know CiviCRM already checks for updates and obviously has some pretty complex email functionality.

Have they been tied together in a similar way -- for example, to allow an email address or group to receive an email if a security release is ready?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is a security notification civicrm group that you can subscribe to on civicrm.org

https://civicrm.org/advisory/subscribe

2. Security updates and notifications have not been tied as yet. Definitely this would be a good addition to the project

Answer (score 3):

Note that a lot of work has happened on [CRM-13823](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13823) that would facilitate this, primarily a rewrite of the System.check API.  That work will land in 4.7 - it's not merged in core, but can be found [here](https://github.com/ginkgostreet/civicrm-core/tree/status-page).

If you want the functionality you're describing now, and you run Nagios/Icinga, consider installing [CiviMonitor](https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.civimonitor).

Answer (score 3):

Note that in 4.6 the in-app notifications have already been improved to display security updates as different from normal updates, and seperate display preferences for both.

[image]